# How to create this type of array in javascript in api call using Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
"Official_time": { 
            "1": { 
                    "from" : "10:00 am", 
                    "to" :"5:00 pm" 
                }, 
            "3": { 
                    "from" : "10:00 am", 
                    "to" :"5:00 pm" 
                } 
}
```

I want when "I am select first day of week than I will get its value one and like each day I get Its value like 1 to 7 but if I am select days than only its value 1 to 7 gets. I am using checkbox for days.

Another things is I need store 'open time' & 'close time'  so I using time picker.

So how Can I create single array in javascript for this all value like show in array, and can I call in javascript using Ajax?

Comment: thanks for reply. but how can . i am new in ajax call and javascript.

Comment: I am sorry but we cannot understand what you are asking. Can I suggest you use Google Translate, write the question in your first language and then paste the English translation in your question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all your times stored in a php array to your likings, here's a great starting point to get your php array into JSON: [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)